How to update Airbyte to latest version?
We are using Airbyte for streaming data into our environment. We have forked the GitHub repository given at this location
https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte
We have done some customizations in our forked Git repository for authentication and authorization and some custom coding for streaming data. We create Docker images of the Airbyte connectors and deploy in our environment.
Since the time we forked repository, the main repository of GitHub has done many changes and our repository is quite behind the main branch. Recently Airbyte has announced that they are going to release a major version in few days.
What is the easiest and best way to update our repository? If we update, will we also lose our customization code?

This sounds like a Git question, and it is not about GitHub or Airbyte at all. The main answer is create a new fork from the latest version, and cherry-pick your changes onto it. If then do not play back seamlessly then you may have to re-apply your changes manually.
